# Beginner : problem with global style in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

In first, sorry for my english ^^

I'm doing an application in wpf, with c# language.
I try to apply a button style for all my buttons, labels and textboxs, to have the property TextWrapping="Wrap" every where. I do this Resource :

```
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

It does what I want :
[My buttons render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeXQ9.png).
But now, I would like to put an image, but this style imposes itself and I don't know how to cancel this style.
I tried :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="icon_exit" Source="src/icon_exit.png"/>
        <Image x:Key="icon_info" Source="src/icon_info.png"/>
        <Image x:Key="icon_fullscreen" Source="src/icon_fullscreen.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

and

```
<Button Click="RobotInfoPage" Content="{StaticResource icon_info}" Grid.Column="10" Padding="10"/>
<Button Click="ToogleFullscreen"Content="{StaticResource icon_fullscreen}"Grid.Column="11" Padding="10"/>
<Button Click="Exit" Content="{StaticResource icon_exit}" Background="Red" Grid.Column="12" Padding="10"/>
```

But it is not the solution :
[My buttons render with picture -> Empty buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjnSI.png)

If someone could me explain who do that, it will be super !  :)

Thank's to you.

Comment: Make sure that `src/icon_exit.png` etc is a valid assembly resource path. There should be a project folder named `src` in your Visual Studio project, in which you put the image files. The image files itself should have their Build Action set to Resource (-> context menu on the file in the project in Solution Explorer).

Comment: Yes i'm sur that the path are correct. For another project, I'm doing the same thing and it's ok. The path are not the problem